# Spring MVC Get file under WEB-INF without a request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to get hold of a file ( or a directory ) under `/WEB-INF/.../`

outside of a request. I need it in a bean loaded at server startup.

All solutions I can find either wants an XML file using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` or a request to get the servlet context or using the current executing class. Seems ugly to me.

How can I get a `File("/WEB-INF/myDir/")`. There has to be a way, no!?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As long as your bean is declared in web application context you can obtain an instance of `ServletContext` (using `ServletContextAware`, or by autowiring).

Then you can access files in webapp directory either directly (`getResourceAsStream()`, `getRealPath()`), or using `ServletContextResource`.

EDIT by momo:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

... myMethod() { 
     File rootDir = new File( servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/myDIR/") );
}
```

Comment: +1 for `servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/myDIR/")`

Comment: The solution contributed by @mahesh just below is much better, because the Service Layer shouldn't have dependencies from the Web Layer. ServletContext only should be perform in Controllers and something like that.

Comment: Plus, getRealPath method may return null depending on which application server and/or the application has been deployed such as a .war in weblogic.

Answer (score 11):

I use **Spring** *DefaultResourceLoader* and *Resource* to read inside WEB-INF or any resources in a *.jar file. Work like a charm. Good luck!

```
import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public static void myFunction() throws IOException {
    final DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();               
    LOGGER.info(loader.getResource("classpath:META-INF/resources/img/copyright.png").exists());             
    Resource resource = loader.getResource("classpath:META-INF/resources/img/copyright.png");           
    BufferedImage watermarkImage = ImageIO.read(resource.getFile());
}
```

Comment: `DefaultResourceLoader` can't read inside of WEB-INF, you will need `ServletContextResource` for this

Comment: @Derp Could you please provide more information about how to implement ServletContextResource in Service Layer? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("files/test.xml").getFile());
```

"files" folder should be child of "main/resources" folder

Answer (score 2):

You can use classpath resource if the file is located in the `WEB_INF\classes` directory. Which is where any files in your `src/main/resources` directory will be copied to using a normal maven build ...

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource
...
final Resource yourfile = new ClassPathResource( "myfile.txt");
```

Comment: `/WEB-INF/myDir/` is not a classpath resource.

Comment: @axtavt oh yeah, assumed it was WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it if you just want to access it from a Service (not through ServletContext):

```
    final DefaultResourceLoader loader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    Resource resource = loader.getResource("classpath:templates/mail/sample.png");
    File myFile = resource.getFile();
```

Note that the last line may throw `IOException` so you need to catch / rethrow

Note, that the file is here:
`src\main\resources\templates\mail\sample.png`

Comment: Thanks, but the question was about getting it under WEB-INF

Answer (score -1):

Not completely related to your question, but...
Here is some universal sulution i used to load properties from anywhere in web application like Spring does it (supporting WEB-INF/..., classpath:..., file:...). Is is based on using `ServletContextResourcePatternResolver`. You will need `ServletContext`.

```
private static Properties loadPropsTheSpringWay(ServletContext ctx, String propsPath) throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean springProps = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new ServletContextResourcePatternResolver(ctx);
    springProps.setLocation(resolver.getResource(propsPath));
    springProps.afterPropertiesSet();
    return springProps.getObject();
}
```

I used the above method in my custom servlet context listener while conext was not yet loaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.pdf");
```