# Reading a JSON file in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using JAVA 8, Servlet 3.1 and springMVC without the `web.xml`. I have placed a `info.json` file in `src\main\resources\data`. There is a util class from which i am trying to read the file. No matter what path i give am unable to read it. i get below exception :

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: WEB-INF\classes\data\info.json
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
>           at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)

I am trying to read the file as below :

```
public static <T> T unMarshal(String json, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("WEB-INF\\classes\\data\\info.json"));
        return  objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, clazz);
    }
```

also tried paths like

`C:\\domain\\src\\main\\resources\\data\\info.json
src\\main\\resources\\data\\info.json
data\\info.json`

I have tried different paths also tried fully qualified path still unable to read it. Also tried [File path to resource in our war/WEB-INF folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340653/file-path-to-resource-in-our-war-web-inf-folder) but unable to get hold of the context instance. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Your resource is an entry of your jar or war file. It's not a file on the file system. WEB-INF/classes is in the classpath of your webapp. Use YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream() to load the bytes of this resource. Not file IO.

Comment: `YourClass.getResourceAsStream()` does not exists for my class.

Comment: Sorry. YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream().

Comment: you can refer this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210465/spring-mvc-get-file-under-web-inf-without-a-request)

Answer (score 0):

try to get the path of the current directory and file with:

```
String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println (filePath);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath + "/src/DBTextFiles/Administrator.txt"));
```